# Ввод списка классов и их сортировка по времени

Tags: java, classloader

1. > Создать `ArrayList` и ввести имена всех классов в него и каждому присвоить  соответствующее значение (DataModified) равное дате последнего изменения в миллисекундах с 1970 1 января GMT +0

   Частично решение уже найдено, благодаря вашему сообществу и конкретно Алексею Шиманскому. Список классов мы получили.

   ```
   public static List<Class> find(String pkgname) {
       List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();

       File directory = null;
       String relPath = pkgname.replace('.', '/'); 

       URL resource = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(relPath); 
       if (directory != null && directory.exists()) {
           // получаем содержимое пакета
           String[] files = directory.list();
           for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
               // достаем из него только файлы с расширением .class
               if (files[i].endsWith(".class")) {
                   // убираем расширение .class
                   String className = files[i].substring(0, files[i].length() - 6);
               }
           }
       }

       return classes;
   }
   ```

   Дату изменения конкретного файла мы тоже можем получить через `lastModified(milliseconds)`

   Вопрос в том, как это привязать друг к другу, чтобы оно в комплексе получало это и возвращало в удобночитаемом формате.
2. > Обновить эту информацию 1 раз при запуске программы а в дальнейшем пользоваться ей, а не обращаться к ClassLoader каждый раз.
3. > По запросу (по первым буквам) выводить из массива 10 штук имен, отсортированных в первую очередь по времени (недавно изменённые-впереди), а во вторую(если дата одинаковая) то по алфавиту.

   Тут вероятно следует применить сортировку по 2 параметрам. С первым параметром все ясно, так как время изменения – это число, то просто сортируем по его убыванию(самые первые результаты выдаются для наибольших чисел, т.е. для недавно изменённых объектов.  Со вторым параметром тоже все ясно – вывод по алфавиту тоже вроде бы прост.

   Вопрос в том как это соединить  в одном, чтобы возвращало 10 значений по времени, а если среди них встретятся одинаковые – то по алфавиту.

Answer (score 1):

Замена `List<Class>` на `Map<Long, Class>` должна помочь.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: В Мар передается пара значений. Единственное, в чем вопрос - может ли время создания файлов быть одинаковым? Если да - то тогда лучше HashMap, где вторым параметром будет класс, который содержит время создания и название класса.

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Map даёт возможность привязать одно значение к другому через ключ, а как сортировать то их? Сначала по одному, затем по другому признаку?

Comment: Хорошая статья про коллекции: http://www.quizful.net/post/Java-Collections. Для того, чтобы реализовать сортировку - можно переопределить функции сomparator(), hashCode() и equals() под свои нужды.